# Why embedded systems are called as embedded systems?

Tags: embedded, system

In most of the times we try to guess the meaning of terms from its name or title itself. For example diodes are electronic devices with two (di) electrodes connected together. Resistors are electronic components which resist flow of current.

Likewise I think, microcontrollers or embedded systems should also have meaning hidden within the term itself.

So

-why embedded systems are called as embedded systems? 
In oher words, What is required in the system to be termed as Embedded system?

Comment: Look it up in a dictionary

Comment: The line between embedded and not has become very fuzzy with the numerous devices we now have.  many years ago you would think of things like the mcu and software inside a clock radio, or inside a television set, or a car stereo as an embedded system.  And the thing in your beige computer box as not an embedded system.  But now, is your smart phone an embedded system or just the latest computer?  It is a little bit of both.  Embedded would mean what the word means, embedded in something else.  often with one purpose and limited resources.

Comment: A system serves  a specific purpose and the functionality of that purpose is executed and controlled by a miniature controller, that is embedded within the system. A system can be  such as a micro-oven, air conditioner, temperature control unit, digital fuel indicator etc.

Comment: @devraj this site has a little bit of a different format than you may be used two, it has a Q&A format. Typically questions that will lead to discussion are discouraged. Questions must be specific and should have specific answers, this question has no specific answer. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  It may also be useful for you to take the tour: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour and get more familiar with how the community operates.

Answer (score 10):

"Embedded systems" are controllers (or computers) which are DESIGNED INTO (and built INSIDE) of the larger product.  As distinguished from general-purpose controllers (or computers) which are separate, stand-alone products.

Comment: @devraj embedded = [to embed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/embed?s=t)

Comment: Do you understand what the word "embed" means?  It means: "To fix (an object) firmly and deeply in a surrounding mass." It means that the system is part of a larger product (or system).  For example virtually all modern vehicles have an Electronic Engine Controller (EEC). It is a rather complex controller which uses many sensors throughout the vehicle to control fuel, spark, etc. That is an excellent example of an "embedded controller". The engine controller is "embedded" inside the vehicle and is an integral part of it.

Comment: I think of an embedded controller or computer as one hidden inside some other equipment, such that the average user is not aware of the controller's existance.  There are many embedded controllers in a modern car, but the driver is not aware of them, and doesn't directly interact with them, as they would with a normal computer.

Comment: Embedded controllers have no direct user access or expansion slots, but often offer a 1uS RTC for dedicated applications. It is typical for them to offer USB for keyboard/mouse, and a HDMI monitor port. If for spacecraft, even these ports will be omitted.

Comment: As a software engineer who has been building embedded systems for a couple of decades, I sometimes have to explain what I do to friends and family. I say that I program the computers inside things that you don't think of as computers. Examples include microwaves, automobile engines, security cameras and telephones.

Answer (score 0):

I would also say that an embedded system performs a dedicated function, versus a general purpose computing platform whose function is determined by a user-selected software application. An embedded system is also typically a functional element within a larger system—e.g., an assembly that performs the CONTROL function within a feedback control system.